# Checking if a directory exists in FTP without relying on exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, exception, ftp

I've written a method to check if a directory already exists on an FTP server. The only way I could see to make this work was to return a different result from the method if an exception is thrown - very bad practice in my opinion. Is there a better way to write this?

```
public bool DirectoryExists(string directory)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
        throw new ArgumentException("No directory was specified to check for");

    // Ensure directory is ended with / to avoid false positives
    if (!directory.EndsWith("/"))
        directory += "/";

    try
    {
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(directory);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

        using (request.GetResponse())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The connection hostname, username and password referred to within this block of code are auto properties set when the class is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

- don't omit braces `{}` for single `if` statements. Using braces in this case will make your code less errorprone.
- you want to return a state, which represents a specific states which shouldn't be restricted to only two states. This just calls for an **enum**.

  ```
  public enum FtpResponse
  {
      DirectoryExists, DirectoryNotFound, DirectoryNotSpecified
  }


  public FtpResponse DirectoryExists(string directory)  
  {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
      {
           return FtpResponse.DirectoryNotSpecified;
      } 
      // the rest of the code

  }
  ```

Comment: I think it's better to throw an argument exception if the argument is invalid rather that returning another enum value. The single line `if` suggestion isn't helpful either, it's just one of the useless programmer holy wars.

Answer (score 1):

### (Missing) Specification

You are lacking a clear specification (comments). The way you implemented it, you consider *not exists* and *don't know whether it exists* as one and the same. I would expect a method called `DirectoryExists` to:

- return `true` when the directory exists
- return `false` when it does not exist
- throw an exception when unabe to determine existence

Let consumers handle exceptions:

```
catch (WebException)
{
    //return false;
    throw;                  // if we don't log here, remove the catch altogether
}
```

It may very well be possible you cannot find a way to determine when to return `false`. In such case, the method either returns `true` or throws an exception. I would allow such behavior to be forward-compatible in case we ever do find a way to return `false` without impacting legacy consumer code.

If the purpose of this method is not to swallow exceptions (as your question title suggests), and only to return `true` or `false`, you should definately put in the specification that the method is a sand-box.

#### Valid paths

Isn't it possible that an empty path means the current directory?

> ```
> if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
>     throw new ArgumentException("No directory was specified to check for");
> ```

Not sure whether edge cases could escape your code below. But I would favour dispatching as much as we can to built-in functionality.

> ```
> // Ensure directory is ended with / to avoid false positives
> if (!directory.EndsWith("/"))
>     directory += "/";
> ```

`GetFullPath` ensures at most one folder separator are appended. So I've turned the condition around. Always add the separator, and let `GetFullPath` clean it up.

```
directory = Path.GetFullPath(directory + "/");
```